# Listings color context sensitive keywords (Matlab)

Tags: formatting, listings, code, matlab

In Matlab there's two ways to use `end`:

1. to end `if`s, `while`s etc.
2. to refer to the last item in an array/vector (example: `v(end)` or `v(end-1)`).

I want to use `listings` to include some matlab code in my document, and I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75124/182889) answer explaining how to do it (including a very nice formatting).
The problem is that the line `emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{blue},` treats all `end`s equally, highlighting even when they shouldn't (case 2 above).
In this very basic example:
[image]

My code would actually be a bit more complex but provided a valid solution is given I should be able to adapt it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Here's the **MWE** to the output above:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.m}
for i=1:3
  x(i)=i;
end % this should be blue

y = x(end); % this shouldn't
\end{filecontents*}


\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0}
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[2]{(end)},emphstyle=[2]\color{black}, %doesn't work...
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{blue}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{foo.m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will be rather difficult because it requires parsing (is this statement closing a for/if/while block or not) instead of pattern matching (is this a known keyword with possibly a bit of local context). So I think it will not be possible. A small test of different editors and highlighters (gEdit, Geany and Pygments) also showed that none of them does it right, are you aware of any highlighter outside of Matlab/Octave itself that actually produces the desired behavior?

Comment: @Marijn I tried to define `emph=[2]{(end)}` for example (also in the code above), which should match only the 2nd "end", but I can't get it to override the blue highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `matlab-prettifier` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.m}
for i=1:3
  x(i)=i;
end % this should be blue

y = x(end); % this shouldn't
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{foo.m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile: "Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

Process exited with error(s)"

Comment: Why did you comment out the `\usepackage{listings}`?

Comment: @Superuser27 are you using pdflatex to compile?

Comment: @Superuser27 `matlab-prettifier` is built on top of `listings`. So need not load it again. That’s why I commented it.

Comment: yes I'm using pdflatex

Comment: @Superuser27 I am using texlive 2018 and it works fine for me. It works in overleaf also. I don't know why it is not working for you. Can you try compiling after changing `basicstyle` from `\mlttfamily,` to `\ttfamily`.

Comment: Yes, changing to `\ttfamily` works! Also removing the whole `\lstset{...}` and using `\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{foo.m}`.